# Bluetooth connection between a smartwatch (Wear OS) and an Arduino Nano BLE 33

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, wear-os

I'm a student and I'm new in Android's world.

What I want to do is try to connect my smartwatch to Arduino Nano BLE 33 (because I should show Arduino's  data on my smarwatch).

First of all I try to  use this guide [Bluetooth low energy](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le) but I failed(probably I do something wrong).
Then I read this [Bluetooth overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth) and I tried to develope an app for smartphone (because It's more easy) and I obtained this:

```js
MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button scanButton;
ListView scanListView;
ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
BluetoothAdapter myAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
    scanListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.scanned_list);

    scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myAdapter.startDiscovery();
        }
    });

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,stringArrayList);
    scanListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}

BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            stringArrayList.add(device.getName());
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};
}
```

It works on my smartphone and my smartphone detects Arduino.
Now I would like to get the same with the smartwatch but I don't know to change the code.

Can someone help me??

I'm so sorry if my ask is stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Considering this code for wear os:

```js
public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity {

    private TextView text;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
    private ListView scanList;
    //private ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    //private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    private Button scanButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        // recuperiamo un riferimento al BluetoothManager
        // BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        // recuperiamo un riferimento all'adapter Bluetooth
        btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        // verifichiamo che Bluetooth sia attivo nel dispositivo
        if (btAdapter == null || !btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }

        // premendo il bottone inizio la ricerca dei dispositivi
        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btAdapter.startDiscovery();
                text.setText("Ricerca dispositivi");
            }
        });

        // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered.
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

        //scanList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        // Enables Always-on
        setAmbientEnabled();
    }

    // Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND.
    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Discovery has found a device. Get the BluetoothDevice
                // object and its info from the Intent.
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                text.setText("Ecco il dispositivo trovato");
                //stringArrayList.add(device.getName()); //prendo i nomi dei device
                //String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // MAC address
            }
            else
                text.setText("Nessun dispositivo trovato");
        }
    };
}
```

Could It possible that registerReceiver doesn't work for WearableActivity?